# Haskell error on possible indentation mistakes

Tags: haskell

In the following Hasekll code,

```
func1 :: Int -> [Int]
func1 m = aux 2
  where aux h = 
    | length (func2 h) >= m = take m (func2 h)
    | otherwise              = aux (h + 100)
```

the GHC gives error of

```
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
15 |     | length (primes h) >= m = take m (primes h)
   |     ^

Compilation failed.
```

I didn't use tabs but instead two spaces consistently for indentation. I also retyped the whole function manually once in case I accidentally mixed tabs and spaces at some point. However, I still couldn't figure where this error comes from after about half an hour reading rules on indentation.

Comment: nothing to do with indentation - just remove the `=`. (This is a common error to make with guards when first starting with Haskell - I remember making it many times!)

Comment: You meant replace `where aux h = ` with `where aux h`, right? I did it and somehow the compiler still gives the same error...

Comment: The error goes away when I put `aux h` in a new line...Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes I did mean that. If there's still a parse error you can try indenting the lines with the guards so they're to the right of `aux`.

Comment: You need to indent it at least one character more to the right than the start of `aux`.

Comment: The column where `where` starts is _not_ relevant for indentation purposes. What matters is the column where the word after `where` starts, `aux` in your case. The definition of `aux` must be indented more than that column.

Comment: Yeah it compiles after I follow your instructions. Thanks a lot!